How to simultaneously run multiple instances of a Class which have async functions?
class calculation():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    async def one(self):
        while True:
            print(self.value * 1)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def two(self):
        while True:
            print(self.value * 2)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def starter(self):
        await asyncio.gather(self.one(), self.two())
           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    a = calculation(2)
    b = calculation(3)
   
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=asyncio.run(a.starter()))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=asyncio.run(b.starter()))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

I tried to run the above code, but only first instance (a) runs, (b) is blocked from running, is it possible to run the both instances simultaneously, Thanks.

There is no need to be using threads or child processes based on what one and two are doing:
import asyncio
import time

class Calculation():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    async def one(self):
        for _ in range(3):  # So that we end eventually
            print(f'{self.value} * 1 = {self.value * 1} (time = {time.monotonic() - start_time})')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def two(self):
        for _ in range(3):  # So that we end eventually
            print(f'{self.value} * 2 = {self.value * 2}  (time = {time.monotonic() - start_time})')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def starter(self):
        await asyncio.gather(self.one(), self.two())


async def run_calculations():
    global start_time

    c2 = Calculation(2)
    c3 = Calculation(3)
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    await asyncio.gather(c2.starter(), c3.starter())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_calculations())

Prints:
2 * 1 = 2 (time = 0.0)
2 * 2 = 4  (time = 0.0)
3 * 1 = 3 (time = 0.0)
3 * 2 = 6  (time = 0.0)
2 * 1 = 2 (time = 1.0159999998286366)
3 * 1 = 3 (time = 1.0159999998286366)
2 * 2 = 4  (time = 1.0159999998286366)
3 * 2 = 6  (time = 1.0159999998286366)
2 * 1 = 2 (time = 2.030999999959022)
2 * 2 = 4  (time = 2.030999999959022)
3 * 1 = 3 (time = 2.030999999959022)
3 * 2 = 6  (time = 2.030999999959022)

Update for Multiprocessing
If you really need to use multiprocessing because your asyncio coroutines one and two have some CPU-intensive calculations, I would suggest that you put those calculations into a "regular" method (i.e. not a coroutine), called blocking_code in this demo, and use loop method run_in_executor as follows:
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

class Calculation():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.start_time = time.monotonic()

    def blocking_code(self, multiplier):
        print(f'{self.value} * {multiplier} = {self.value * multiplier} (time = {time.monotonic() - self.start_time})')

    async def one(self, pool):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        for _ in range(3):  # So that we end eventually
            await loop.run_in_executor(pool, self.blocking_code, 1)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def two(self, pool):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        for _ in range(3):  # So that we end eventually
            await loop.run_in_executor(pool, self.blocking_code, 2)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def starter(self, pool):
        await asyncio.gather(self.one(pool), self.two(pool))


async def run_calculations():
    c2 = Calculation(2)
    c3 = Calculation(3)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
        await asyncio.gather(c2.starter(pool), c3.starter(pool))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_calculations())

Prints:
2 * 1 = 2 (time = 0.2190000000409782)
2 * 2 = 4 (time = 0.2190000000409782)
3 * 1 = 3 (time = 0.2190000000409782)
3 * 2 = 6 (time = 0.2190000000409782)
2 * 1 = 2 (time = 1.2190000000409782)
3 * 1 = 3 (time = 1.2190000000409782)
3 * 2 = 6 (time = 1.2350000003352761)
2 * 2 = 4 (time = 1.2350000003352761)
2 * 1 = 2 (time = 2.25)
3 * 1 = 3 (time = 2.25)
2 * 2 = 4 (time = 2.25)
3 * 2 = 6 (time = 2.25)

If blocking_code is not particularly CPU-intensive (for example, it it retrieves a URL using the requests module) but does not use asyncio, then you can initialize pool to a concureent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor instance.

You can use threading:
import asyncio
import threading


class Calculation:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.running = True

    async def one(self):
        while self.running:
            print(self.value * 1, 'one')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def two(self):
        while self.running:
            print(self.value * 2, 'two')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def starter(self):
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(self.one())
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(self.two())
        await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False


def run_calculation(calculation_instance):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(calculation_instance.starter())
    loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, b = Calculation(2), Calculation(3)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_calculation, args=(a,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=run_calculation, args=(b,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join(timeout=1)
    t2.join(timeout=1)

    a.stop()
    b.stop()


Prints
2 one
4 two
3 one
6 two
2 one
4 two
3 one
6 two
2 one
4 two
3 one
6 two


You can use threading, but it's totally unnecessary.

@Booboo You're right. However, for some reason, OP wanted to use multiprocessing. This is an alternative to multiprocessing.

Multithreading is not an alternative to multiprocessing if methods one and two are CPU-intensive and is totally unnecessary if they are not. Given that one and two as provided by the OP have no CPU-intensive operations, multiprocessing or multithreading accomplishes nothing except additional overhead (my answer's first code example is all you need). And if we assume that the OP's methods (not shown) actually contain CPU-intensive operations, then there is a solution using multiprocessing (see my answer's second code example).

@Booboo "Multithreading is not an alternative to multiprocessing". Of course is not. I did not imply that. Just for some reasons, OP was using multiprocessing in this context with asyncio. ProcessPoolExecutor() is an overkill. Thanks for the comment!

And my point is that using threads is also overkill and adds inefficiencies when the OP's code can be run with asyncio-only code.
